# Integrability of function

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the function $u(t,x)=e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2+1}}$. I would like to show the integrability of this function.

**My attempt:**

Since I am only considering the interval [-1,1] then I have:

$\int_{[-1,1]}e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2+1}} d\lambda(x) = \int_{-1}^{1}e^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2+1}} dx$

I was stuck here. Then I realized that the function is measurable and Riemann integrable and therefore $u \in \mathcal{L}^{1}(\lambda)$. This means that I do not need to specifically show that $\int u d\lambda(x) < \infty$.

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Actually any Riemann integrable function is Lebesgue measurable. Any Riemann integrable function must be bounded, say, $|f|\leq M$. So with an integration over bounded interval $[-1,1]$, it must be $\displaystyle\int_{[-1,1]}|f|\leq 2M<\infty$.

Comment: Appreciate the response. I have a followup question. Can the derivative of $u(t,x)$ be bounded by an integrable function? Since we are considering the interval $[-1,1]$ then I would bound the derivative as $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(t,x) = \frac{te^{\sqrt{x^2+t^2+1}}}{\sqrt{x^2+t^2+1}} \leq \frac{te^{\sqrt{x^2+2}}}{\sqrt{x^2+2}} $. This majorant is measurable and Riemann integrable.

Comment: What is the range of your $t$?

Comment: $t \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Since $t$ is fixed, actually the fraction is of course bounded as $x\in[-1,1]$ and the denominator has no singularity.

Comment: I am not familiar with the word singularity! But would you agree to the above inequalities?

Comment: Singularity means that $1/0$ somehow like this. The inequality is not correct, you should have $\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$ in the denominator and the numerator cannot be reduced since $t$ is fixed, that is, the numerator is $e^{\sqrt{x^{2}+t^{2}+1}}$.

Comment: I got it. Appreciate it!